# why isn't my code working to check if username has already been taken?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM users");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!empty($_POST)){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if ($username == $row['username']){
echo "Username Taken, Try again";
}else if (empty($username) || !isset($username)) {
echo "Please enter a valid username";
 } else if (empty($email) || !isset($email)){
```

I want to check whether the username is already taken when they update or register their details. I have noticed that i check if the username field is empty and set AFTER i check whether its been taken. I will change this. However, i can still register a username that is already taken?

Comment: Seriously you do it like that? You should be using `mysqli_num_rows()` for doing this, for example, `SELECT username from table_name WHERE username = $the_posted_username` and than use the `mysqli_num_rows()` function to compare the row count.

Comment: No matter what you think, `SELECT * FROM mytable` is not the only SQL you'll ever need to learn. Seriously.

Comment: how did you get $username.... ?

Comment: Have you thought about `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username` instead?

Comment: So you do a SELECT over ALL users since there is no WHERE Clause.
Then you check if it is a POST Request.
So whenever this script runs, you waste precious Recources.

Comment: @h2ooooooo PDO will bounce over his head as of now, the next question he will ask is whats `:username`?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Samuel there is no question of debugging, the program is totally incorrect

Comment: @Mr.Alien Prepared statements work fine in `mysqli`. If I write `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'` he'll come back in 2 days with a flawed site because this is pasted everywhere.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It seems like he is a beginner, he won't get it that its a placeholder, so I didn't posted a PDO sample... :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Even the more reason to teach him to do things right the first time. He'll most likely copy this line of code and modify it every time he needs an SQL query. At *least* make an effort and use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to provide *some* sort of safety net. Also, as said, MySQLi supports prepared statements as well - it's not a PDO thing :)

Comment: I am a beginner. Jeeze.

Comment: @h2ooooooo See ^^^ and nah, now I don't do that anymore, I mean the PDO suggestion, read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143382/205030)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like some of the comments said, let me re-phrase it for you.

Ideally, you should be checking if the username exists in the table instead of fetching all the username and check against each (which is redundant and not needed).

So you should be doing:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
  //get the submitted username cleaned
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['username']);
  //get username where username=posted username 
  $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'");
  //get the number of rows returned from above query
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  //if a row is found, that means the username exists
  //so post the error
  if($count==1){
    echo "Username Taken, Try again";
  }
}
```

Look up on **prepared statements** with **mysqli**. It automatically does the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function for you and is more secure against injection. I have just started learning it on PDO so I'm not familiar with the **mysqli** way of doing it and thus couldn't put it up with this answer.

Comment: Would love to hear from the DV!